# how to delete all rows with empty field via function/trigger combo in Postgres v 9.3?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

In PostgreSQL 9.3 I am trying to write a trigger function that will be called after updates to table `test2` and that will delete rows of `test2` where field "email" is empty. Here's my attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean_emp() RETURNS trigger AS                                                                                                                                                                         
$$
BEGIN
DELETE FROM test2 WHERE email=null;
return test2;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Then I set up the trigger like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_empty2
AFTER UPDATE OF name ON test2 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE clean_emp();
```

This gives me an error when I then do an update on table test2:

```
update test2 set name = name || 'fesgses';
ERROR:  column "test2" does not exist
```

And here's my data table for completeness:

```
  name  |    email
--------+-------------
 hi     | hiemail
 shoe   |
 shoe2  |
 cathy  |
```

If anyone can give me some pointers on where I'm going wrong, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong with this trigger.

First: your delete statement. You can't compare `NULL` using `=`. You need to use `IS NULL`:

```
DELETE FROM test2 WHERE email IS NULL;
```

Second: a trigger function ([quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)) "*must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.*"

So `return test2;` should be `return new;`.

Third: you created a **row level** trigger, which is going to be very bad for performance. As you are not dependent on the actual values that are changed by the update, a *statement level*  trigger will be much more efficient, because it only fires **once** for each `UPDATE` statement rather than once for each row that has been changed.

In a statement level trigger the return value is ignored, so the suggested `return new;` from above becomes a `return null;` as there is no `new` or `old` record available in a statement level trigger.

Putting it all together:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean_emp() 
  RETURNS trigger AS                                                                           $$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM test2 WHERE email IS NULL;
  return NULL; -- as we are now using a statement level trigger, null is fine
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_empty2
AFTER UPDATE OF name ON test2 
  FOR EACH STATEMENT --<< fire only once for each statement, not row
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE clean_emp();
```

If you also want to disallow empty values ( `''` is something different than 'NULL') you would need to change the condition to `where coalesce(email, '') = '')`

---

But the trigger approach is wrong to begin with: you should declare the `email` column as `NOT NULL` and then nobody will ever be able to put `NULL` values into that column and therefore you don't need the trigger at all.

Comment: A big +2 for the last sentence